# Rails erb Json view conditional rendering

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, ruby-on-rails-3.2, erb

When I try this, I get {a: 1, b:} for c not present. When c is present I get {a:1,b:1} which is right. But how can I hide the node b conditionally so that I could only get {a:1}?

```
{"a":   <%= json @teams.count %>
,"b":   <%= json @teams.num if @c.present? %>}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a ruby hash to `json` and it will figure it out correctly

```
<%= json( a: @teams.count, b: (@teams.num if @c.present?) ) %>
```

The problem with your method is that you are trying to render the string yourself, but `nil` is being rendered as blank space instead of an empty string `''`.  You could theoretically fix it like this:

```
{"a":   <%= json @teams.count %>
,"b":   <%= json(@c.present? ? @teams.num : '' %>}
```

but you can avoid most of the hassle if you use the first method.